# Deploying nodejs project on ec2 through gitlab pipeline

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, yaml, continuous-integration, cicd

I have an aws EC2 instance running, mysql and node installed, and a small database.
On gitlab I have a node/express backend.
My goal is to achieve this: when I push to main branch of the repo, I want a pipeline to be triggered and my backend should update.
I have a ssh key inserted into gitlab (deploy keys). Im using aws free tier so I will not use any other services beside ec2.
My problem is, I dont know how to write a yaml script for this.
I can not find a good example.
Can anyone explain it to me or give me a good example?

I tried finding a good example online, but i did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll try to show you an example of using a simple flow:

1. Push/merge some changes on the master branch.
2. Run CI to execute the pipeline.
3. Do something before the script runs.
4. Execute a bash script on EC2.

The first step is to clone your project with SSH. In this example, I assume the repository is cloned into the directory /home/project, and when running the project, I recommend using pm2.

Create a bash script on your EC2 server:

```
    # Pull code
    cd /home/project
    git checkout master
    git pull origin master
    
    # Build and deploy
    yarn install
    pm2 restart server
```

Save it into /home/deploy/deploy.sh (you can change the path).

Next, GitLab must have access to your EC2 server. I recommend using an SSH key. Add a secret key to your GitLab

> settings -> CI/CD -> Variables

. In this example, the key name is SSH_PRIVATE_KEY.

Create a .gitlab-ci.yml file in the root of your project:

```
Deploy to Production:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    # accessing EC2/server then running deploy.sh
    # you also can put xxxx@xxxxx -p xxxx to CI/CD variable
    # for ex it become : ssh $IP_SERVER "/home/deploy/deploy.sh"
    - ssh xxxx@xxxxx -p xxxx "/home/deploy/deploy.sh"
  before_script:
    # Setup SSH deploy keys
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

You can modify the deploy.sh script according to the workflow of your current project.

Please note that this example assumes you have already set up the necessary SSH access and configured the variables correctly in GitLab CI/CD settings. Also, remember to handle sensitive data securely, especially when using SSH keys in the CI/CD pipeline.

I hope this helps you.